# Route data to @yield section in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm new in Laravel and need to pass data to navbar in header.

This are my pages

Main:

```
 <div class="container">
    <header>
        @include('user.includes.header')
    </header>

    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>

    <footer>
        @include('user.includes.footer')
    </footer>
</div>
```

Header:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="dropdown">
                @foreach($categorias as $cat)
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="{{$cat->nome}}">
                        {{$cat->nome}}
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                @endforeach
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

IncludesController:

```
class IncludesController extends Controller
{
    public function Header(){
        $categorias = Categoria::all();
        return compact('categorias');
}
    }
}
```

I want to pass data form Controller to header.
I tried this route:

`Route::get('header', 'IncludesController@Header');`

but doesn't work and with this route:

`Route::get('/', 'IncludesController@Header');`

only shows the data and o want to all HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

In IncludesController u need to return :

```
 class IncludesController extends Controller
 {
 public function Header(){
    $categorias = Categoria::all();
    return view('main',compact('categorias');
  }
}
}
```

I hope your main.blade.php file is directly under resources/views folder.

This is untested but it might probably help...

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning your content view from your controller, the data to pass to that view is the second parameter.

```
return view('yourContentView', compact('categorias'));
```

As long as your content view `@extends('main')`, any data passed to your content view would also be made available to both your header and footer views.

Another solution would be to setup a view composer for both your header and footer views.  This will fire each time those views are loaded and automatically inject data into that view...

You can read documentation on the view composers at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers